# Python shelve key error from threading?

Tags: python, database, multithreading

** Importantly, this error does not occur all the time. It pops up every now and then, so I don't believe my code is at fault here.**

Hello, I am using threading along with Python 3.7 shelves. I have a dictionary object inside my shelf. Is this an error caused by threading/simultaneous access? (Using python's Threading library).

Relevant code is merely:

```
requestLibrary[requestID]
```

I am certain that this works, the key has been placed inside the library. But for some instances, the I get this key error. I suspect it has to do with the threading.

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: '4fGdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/lme/Workflow/Source/busDriver.py", line 189, in busDriver
    while 'workflowEndingPoint'.lower() not in str(requestLibrary[requestID]).lower():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
KeyError: b'4fGdb'
```

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code also ?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan, I have posted the relevant code, but as I was saying, it runs fine most of the time. My concern is more so regarding any potential compatibility issues with the theading library and shelves.